# .git/config and .gitmodules not in sync

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want to pull code from the referenced submodules. I tried `git submodule update --init` which does not do anything.

Reading up, I realized that this could be perhaps because my .git/config file isnt set. 
My .git/config does not contain anything about the submodule.

.git/config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://ShubhamRathi@gerrit.opnfv.org:29418/opnfvdocs
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "gerrit"]
    url = ssh://ShubhamRathi@gerrit.opnfv.org:29418/opnfvdocs.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/gerrit/*
[user]
    email = shubhamiiitbackup@gmail.com
[branch "Testingdoc"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

However my .gitmodule contains the references to the submodules

```
[submodule "docs/testing/docs/submodules/apex"]
    path = docs/testing/docs/submodules/apex
    url = https://gerrit.opnfv.org/gerrit/apex
[submodule "docs/testing/docs/submodules/armband"]
    path = docs/testing/docs/submodules/armband
    url = https://gerrit.opnfv.org/gerrit/armband
```

My question is, how do I bring these both files in sync that on `git submodule update --init`, the relevant repositories are pulled up?

Answer (score -3):

you have to run

`git submodule update`

after running `git submodule init`

`git submodule update` is the one that really pulls all your submodules in and checkout a working copy of the referenced sha

Comment: That doesn't works because .git/config file is not changed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028437/how-to-change-git-submodules-url-locally/42035018?noredirect=1