# How to change git submodules url locally?

Tags: git, git-submodules

The original `.gitmodules` file uses the hard coded `https` urls but for some automated tests I clone from `ssh` and make the submodule urls relative as in `../ModuleName`. I don't want to push these changes back into the repo either.

```
# change the https://github.com/ with git@github.com:
sed -i 's/https:\/\/github.com\//git@github.com:/g' ".git/config"
# delete the url lines from the submodule blocks of .git/config
sed -i '/submodule/ {$!N;d;}' ".git/config"
# change hardcoded https:// urls of submodules to relative ones
sed -i 's/https:\/\/github.com\/ProjName/../g' ".gitmodules"
# also make the same change in the .git/modules/*/config
sed -i 's/https:\/\/github.com\/ProjName/../g' .git/modules/*/config
# sync and update
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init --recursive --remote
```

With the snippet above, it does what I want. However, the annoying thing is, `.git/modules/` folder doesn't seem to be under version control but if I just delete it, `git submodule sync` and most other Git operations just stop working.

Is there a way to get the `.git/modules` regenerated after modifying the `.gitmodules` and `.git/config` files?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want to modify the URL used for a submodule only for the local repo, then don't modify the `.gitmodules` file, that is only for changes that you want to push.

Instead, first initialize the local submodule config:

```
git submodule init
```

Then modify the `.git/config` file to change the submodule URL as usual.  (Again, no need to modify `.gitmodules` here, and if this is a new clone you probably won't have `.git/modules` yet.)

As [@jthill points out](//stackoverflow.com/questions/42028437/how-to-change-git-submodules-url-locally/42035018?noredirect=1#comment71246333_42035018), an easier way to modify the submodule URLs is:

```
git config submodule.moduleName.url ssh://user@server/path
```

At this point you **don't** want to run `git submodule sync`, because that will overwrite the changes you just made with the values from the `.gitmodules` file. Instead, go straight to:

```
git submodule update --recursive --remote
```

Comment: Yes, this answers my original question and thank you very much. As a slightly different question, is there a way to recreate the `.git/modules` folder if it gets messed up some how? Because, once it's created, if I delete it manually, almost all git commands are upset from that point onwards.

Comment: @abdus_salam Possible solution [here](//stackoverflow.com/a/36983168/2747593).

Comment: Take a look at the [git submodule init](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-init--ltpathgt82308203) documentation, it's a clear explanation of how this works and why.

Comment: A drawback of this approach is that `git submodule update --remote` may have other side effects, if `submodule.<name>.branch` is set. I would recommend using `git submodule set-url` followed by `git restore .gitmodules`.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this approach has advantages over the accepted answer:

```sh
$ git submodule set-url moduleName ssh://user@server/path
$ git restore .gitmodules  # or: git reset HEAD .gitmodules
```

This will change the URL everywhere, and then set it back to the previous value in the one place you don't want to change (`.gitmodules`).

Why this is better than the accepted answer: when setting the URL with `git config submodule.moduleName.url`, the command used to propagate this change into the actual submodule checkout is `git submodule update --remote`. However, updating the URL is only a side effect of that command, its main use is to (potentially) check out a different commit in the submodule. On the other hand, `set-url` only does what it says on the can.

Answer (score 3):

Not only you can change the submodule URL with `git config submodule.moduleName.url`, but:

- With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), you can **modify** it.
  See "[Git submodule url changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59364554/6309)" and the new command `git submodule set-url [--] <path> <newurl>`
- with Git 2.22 (Q2 2019), you can also **unset** it:

See [commit b57e811](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b57e8119e6e08f731308923ef2b033eb45152bc6), [commit c89c494](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c89c494240a516b082f397130ae44df2e757866b) (08 Feb 2019), and [commit 7a4bb55](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a4bb55f3a47756b5cd9ca2d120c7fe119439e81) (07 Feb 2019) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 01f8d78](https://github.com/git/git/commit/01f8d78887d45dc10f29d3926d5cc52f78838846), 25 Apr 2019)</sup>

> ### `submodule--helper`: teach config subcommand `--unset`
>
> This teaches `submodule--helper config` the `--unset` option, which removes
>   the specified configuration key from the `.gitmodule` file.

That is:

```
git submodule--helper config --unset submodule.submodule.url &&
git submodule--helper config submodule.submodule.url >actual &&
test_must_be_empty actual
```

---

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), the rewriting various parts of "`git submodule`" in C continues, include `set-url`.

See [commit 6417cf9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6417cf9c21e9b3f450cd78352d19f43a4dd5a495) (08 May 2020) by [Shourya Shukla (`periperidip`)](https://github.com/periperidip).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9e8ed17](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e8ed173b4cc4f1855501a7c8ffab6ffbc5bf34d), 13 May 2020)</sup>

> ### [`submodule`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6417cf9c21e9b3f450cd78352d19f43a4dd5a495): port subcommand 'set-url' from shell to C
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Shourya Shukla</sup>
>
> Convert submodule subcommand 'set-url' to a builtin. Port '`set-url`' to '`submodule--helper.c`' and call the latter via '`git submodule.sh`'.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solution but had a mess of problems for some reason.  The following is an alternative.

In a new repository:

1. `git submodule init`
2. Initialize each submodule manually with `git clone ../local/path/to/submodule.git path/in/repo/submodule`

Whenever the root repository submodule hashes change and you need to sync the submodules:

1. Update the root repository
2. `git submodule update` with maybe `--force` and `--recursive` for good measure

Answer (score -1):

I have tried modifying the config file as mentioned, but ran into a new problem:
Now instead of having the wrong URL and getting a fatal error I get this instead:
" fatal: could not get a repository handle for submodule 'xxx\xxxxx\xxx' ".
Merely changing the URL seems to have pushed the problem forward somewhere else, the program still can't reach my desired submodule.

Comment: This does not seem to answer `Is there a way to get the .git/modules regenerated after modifying the .gitmodules and .git/config files?`